# last serial output of a shift register daisy chain

Tags: wiring, shift-register

I'm daisy chaining several shift register. I will work in the serial input parallel output mode.

Is it good pratice to leave the last serial output of the last shift register unconnected? If this is not the case, how should I connect it? I won't need it for further signals.

Thank you!

Comment: The datasheet of your part should tell you what to do with unconnected outputs.

Comment: Put a little plastic cap over the pin so that the bits don't spill all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely leave it unconnected.

For completeness, in very EMI-sensitive application you might put a load resistor on it to dissipate the energy. But those situations are relatively rare.